# Me the Team web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, team

I want a **Meet the Team** space in my Intranet Home page, where I can show the Image and profile details of new employee.  I want to achieve this via OOB feature and if possible then the Web part fetch the employee detail automatically.

Kindly suggest!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Site Users webpart** which is available under **Social Collaboration** group while adding webparts.

When you click a user's name, you see a page that provides information about that user. It includes a presence indicator which you can click to send an e-mail message, schedule a meeting, make a phone call, send an instant message, or add the user to the address book in your e-mail program.

Comment: Thanks Ransher for your response, but the output provided by **Site Users Webpart** is not what I am looking for, it only shows Name!!  My focus is to show Image with Profile details like _Name, Job Title, Email address_ etc..

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve this using OOTB but if you are open to a little Javascript coding using JSOM, you can come up with what you need using a script editor web part. Further details here http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html